# Autofill link text when linking to Documentation

Tags: feature-request, documentation, hyperlinks

When using the Documentation linking feature, it should provide you with good default link text. Namely, the title of the example/feature.

[image]
[image]

In this case, i would like for it to autofill the link text as "Function Scoping".